# Close Keyboard on IOS and Android from Angular 4 typescript

Tags: android, html, ios, angular, typescript

I am creating an app in angular 4 with typescript. The problem I am facing is I want to close the keyboard in mobile when I am displaying a div at the bottom.

As the div is at bottom it is not visible because of the keyboards. So I want to close the keyboards so user can see the div.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it?

```
export class yourComponent ...... {

@ViewChildren('yourTextInput') yourTextInput;

 ngAfterViewInit() {    
    this.yourTextInput.first.nativeElement.blur();     

  }   
}
```

Comment: You should still include the library link in the answer.